# How to locally debug Google apps script?

Tags: debugging, google-apps-script, google-sheets, remote-debugging, clasp

I use clasp with VS Code to locally developing of Google Apps Script. It's too hard to use default code debugger. So I'm looking for some way to debug code locally. Any suggestions how can I do this?

Comment: You can use testing units like qunit. But all such libraries are really old and you need to manually update everything for GAS. Once done though, You can debug locally happily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is **there is no way to debug it as you would do in the editor**.

You can try to make workaround creating testing suites, or introducing various logs. But you cannot go step by step, inspecting variables as you would do normally.

#### Reference

- [Clasp github page](https://github.com/google/clasp/)

Answer (score 2):

It's not the best, but I'm inserting

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt(varNeededToCheck);
```

If it's not the value you are expecting you can cancel the script or you can press OK to continue. It's a workaround and how I'm doing it.

Comment: Is not available for standalone containers